# passing text box value to an open form in c# without making an instance of my first form

Tags: c#

I have a form with many text boxes on it. beside some of its text boxes i used a button that user should click on it to open another form and chose a value from Data grid view  on it that shows selected value  in a text box. by click on  a button this text box value should pass to a text box of first form.

most of codes that I find in internet made an instance from form. but my main form is open and just have to get value from other form.

Answer (score 1):

if you use Linq then it can be very simple.

```
Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Or whatever the form class name is.
You can then get the instance of the form and address the function or property that you want to change.

Comment: @Blazztz0r I did not get the point. you know I want to pass value from text box1 of  form2  to textbox5 of form1 while form1 is open

Comment: Paste your code and I'll try to show a more cleared example.